# Stop thread from any form or thread

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

I have a application that adds items queried from SQL into a list box on my main WPF form. The query takes a long time so I added it to its own thread. I have another thread that shows a new form with a please wait gif animation on it.

So in total I have 3 threads.

1. Main GUI thread
2. Thread running SQL query - thread named sql_thread
3. Thread opens/shows new instance of please wait form with Gif animation on it. - thread name please_wait_thread

I want the ability to cancel the thread running the SQL query from a cancel button on the please_wait_thread that shows a form with a please wait Gif animation.

I am having a real hard time understanding inheritance and how to reference objects between forms. I know how to create new instances of them but not make them communicate.

If I put the below code in the please_wait form and type sql_thread it cannot see the sql thread.

```
public void Cancel_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sql_thread.abort();
}
```

How can I stop the sql_thread in it's tracks when I close the please_wait form?

The code to create the sql_thread on the main form is below.

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread sql_thread = new Thread(sql_search_method);
}
```

P.S. I already tried a backgroundworker but it did not work and once it hits the long query there is no way to stop it until its done with a backgroundworker.

Comment: Firstly, you should just use a DbContext object rather than manually managing your own threads for database calls...

Comment: Use 'Task' and `CancellationToken` (iirc).

Comment: Good to know, do you have a example of how to use CancellationToken from form "B" to cancel a task on form "A"? The communication between forms seem to be my biggest hold up.

Comment: You have to manage this with some sort of factory or container for the tokens and corresponding tasks. `TPL` is your friend